# A question about finding the integrating factors

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$\frac {dy}{dx}=\frac {(xy-y+y^2)}{(x+2y)}$$ how to solve this equation by finding the integrating factors? I tried to find it but it seems didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we start with ste Standard trick here $$y(x)=xv(x)$$ then we have
$$x\frac{dv(x)}{dx}+v(x)+\frac{(x+xv(x)-1)v(x)}{2v(x)+1}$$
and this simplifies to
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}=\frac{(x-2)(v(x)+1)v(x)}{x(2v(x)+1)}$$
$$\frac{dv(x)}{dx}\frac{(2v(x)+1)}{(v(x)+1)v(x)}=\frac{x-2}{x}$$
and we can integrate
$$\int\frac{\frac{dv(x)}{dx}(2v(x)+1)}{(v(x)+1)v(x)}dx=\int\frac{x-2}{x}dx$$

Answer (score 2):

***Hint***

$$dy/dx=\frac{(xy-y+y^2)}{(x+2y)}$$
$$-(xy-y+y^2)dx+(x+2y)dy=0$$
$$\partial_yP-\partial_xQ=-(x+2y)$$
Integrating factor depends only on x
$$\frac {d\mu}{\mu}=-\int dx \implies \mu(x)=e^{-x}$$